# Solr 9 punctuation issue

Tags: search, solr, punctuation

I am migrating Solr 3 to Solr 9. However, the issues I have now are:

1. Solr 9 returns no results where punctuation is included within quotes (a phrase search), such as queries: "Electric Vehicles: Charging Points"
2. Solr 9 treats smart and not-smart apostrophes as different. Could Solr 9 treat them as the same for search? For example: different results for "dog’s breakfast" and "dog's breakfast"

Would these be a configuration issue that can be fixed?

Thanks.

I tried to change the Solrconfig file but could not fix the issue.

Comment: That would depend on the analysis chain you've configured for your field. For the second case you could add a char replacement filter as the first step that replace those characters with a regular single quote.

Comment: Add filter to your field type or create a custom field type and try filter for eg. word delimiter or porter stem or snowball. Use some filter that will remove the ' and ` before indexing and searching. All tokenizers, filters and analyzers are provided by solr on their website with examples. So, its easy to see which one will work for you.